# Problema con webhook de meta

Tags: javascript, python, programación-funcional, programación-bajo-nivel, webhook

Hola como estan? tengo un problema con la api de whatsapp de meta,
miren yo tengo este codigo

```
from flask import Flask, request
import sett
import services

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/webhook', methods=['GET'])
def verificar_token():
    try:
        print(request.args)
        token = request.args.get('hub.verify_token')
        challenge = request.args.get('hub.challenge')

        if token == sett.token and challenge != None:
            return challenge
        else:
            return 'token incorrecto', 403
    except Exception as e:
        return e,403
```

y en sett tengo el token y la url,el problema es que request no me devuelve nada, solo me devuelvo lo siguiente: ImmutableMultiDict([]).
y en services tengo esto:

import requests
import sett
import json

````
def obtener_Mensaje_whatsapp(message):
    if 'type' not in message:
        text = 'mensaje no reconocido'

    typeMessage = message['type']
    if typeMessage == 'text':
        text = message['text']['body']

    return text

def enviar_Mensaje_whatsapp(data):
    try:
        whatsapp_token = sett.whatsapp_token
        whatsapp_url = sett.whatsapp_url
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer' + whatsapp_token}
        response = requests.post(whatsapp_url,
                                headers=headers,
                                data=data)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            return 'mensaje enviado', 200
        else:
            return 'error al enviar mensaje', response.status_code
    except Exception as e:
        return e,403

def text_Message(number,text):
    data = json.dumps(
            {
                "messaging_product": "whatsapp",    
                "recipient_type": "individual",
                "to": number,
                "type": "text",
                "text": {
                    "body": text
                }
            }
    )
    return data

def administrar_chatbot(text,number, messageId, name):
    text = text.lower()#mensaje que envio el usuario
    list = []

    data = text_Message(number,"text")
    enviar_Mensaje_whatsapp(data)```
````

asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd